# Use of undefined constant, but constant is defined in separate file

Tags: php, constants

I have a small configuration file that I'll be using to store global config values, which I've defined as follows:

In config.php:

```
<?php

define('ACTIVE', 1);
define('INACTIVE', 0);
```

In a separate file:

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

...

    public function getData(){

    ...

    $state = ACTIVE;

    ...
    }
```

This yields a `Use of undefined constant ACTIVE` at the above line. Can anyone explain what is wrong?

Comment: Should work as is. Try to make sure you're including the correct file (e.g. place an `echo` in it).

Comment: Please crosscheck the path of config.php